# Yahoo Pipes Regex modifiers

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I have trouble using regex matching on Yahoo Pipes, seems like they don't use the normal Perl syntax.

In the following screenshot "Test" matches exactly "Test", not "test", so matching is case sensitive. How to make it case insensitive?

[image]

```
/Test/i
```

does not work ):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that there are so called "embedded modifiers", so

```
(?i)Test
```

matches now "test" as well as "Test" :-)

Source:
http://discuss.pipes.yahoo.com/Message_Boards_for_Pipes/threadview?m=tm&bn=pip-DeveloperHelp&tid=891&mid=893&tof=-1&rt=2&frt=2&off=1

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html